# How to Run JS Command on an other webpage inside node?

Tags: reactjs, http, react-native

Imagine I go to a certain website and open up console inside chrome, then I say console.log(a_Variable_name); and get a return.
how do I get this same value inside my JS Code/React?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `WebView` to load up your website.

```
<WebView
  source={{ uri: 'https://....'}}
  onMessage={(e) => { console.log(e.nativeEvent.data }}
/>
```

On your website, you need to send the variable via

`window.postMessage(a_Variable_name)`

When trying to integrate this, I had to add a function specified in [this Github thread](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/11594)

```
function waitForBridge() {
  if (window.postMessage.length !== 1) {
    setTimeout(waitForBridge, 200);
  } else {
    window.postMessage(a_Variable_name);
  }
}
window.onload = waitForBridge
```

Comment: The problem is that the Website is not mine.

Comment: I think I can use JQuery as a way to scrap it?